# Opening Contacts app in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am making a react native app and in one screen there is a form in which user has to fill the form in which the user has to fill his mobile number  so I am making a button which will open the contacts app of the user phone and the user can select the conatct number from that list and that number gets filled in the field .

I found this link [react-native-contacts](https://github.com/rt2zz/react-native-contacts) but i think that it is 
taking all the contact Lists and displaying it in the react native app using List View but I do not want this type of functionality . I only want to open the contacts app and then if the user select any particular contact that should be filled in the mobile number field.

Code implementation

```
import ContactsWrapper from 'react-native-contacts-wrapper';
import { Separator, SeparatorDate } from '../../components/List';

export default class AddNewClub extends Component {


  constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    this.onMobileIconPressed = this.onMobileIconPressed.bind(this);

    this.state = {

      registerButtonClicked: false,


    };

  }

  registerButtonClick = () => {


    this.setState({
      registerButtonClicked: true,

    });

  };


  onMobileIconPressed() {
    ContactsWrapper.getContact()
    .then((contact) => {
        // Replace this code
        console.log(contact);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("ERROR CODE: ", error.code);
        console.log("ERROR MESSAGE: ", error.message);
    });
}
```

This is the code which I have written and when I am testing this screen on device then it gives an error "unable to resolve module react-native-contacts-wrapper

Answer (score 1):

you can use [react-native-contacts-wrapper](https://github.com/LynxITDigital/react-native-contacts-wrapper)

Comment: I have used react-native-contacts-wrapper but error is coming when I start the cmponent

Comment: Unable to resolve module 'react-native-contents-wrapper'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same scenario but I didn't find any package which can open native contact list, therefore, I made a screen where I am getting all contacts in ListView.