# open default contacts app in android using react native

Tags: android, react-native

I want to open default contacts app in android in react native and  try this code, but I dont know the correct url of contacts app in android:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL('ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI')}>
      <Text>Press me</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

the error is that no activity found o handle intent

Comment: I didnt find a way to open default contact app, but did you see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48254825/opening-contacts-app-in-react-native ?

Comment: @AlexandrZavalii you can check the answer it is possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know, what do you want to achieve in your app, so I've assumed two scenarios:

**1. Reading/writing the contacts**

It is important to note, that to load the Contacts in your app, you have to request [permissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_CONTACTS) beforehand.

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';

PermissionsAndroid.request(
  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
  {
    'title': 'Contacts',
    'message': 'This app would like to view your contacts.'
  }
).then(() => {
  // open the permissions app
})
```

You also have to add your permission to `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

You might also need WRITE_CONTACTS permission, it depends on what you want to achieve.

Then, you can use [react-native-contacts-wrapper](https://github.com/LynxITDigital/react-native-contacts-wrapper) to open the Contacts app.

**2. Opening the contacts app only**

If you only want to open the contacts app from your app, then you can use the following code:

```
Linking.openURL('content://com.android.contacts/contacts')
```

Comment: it will only get contacts and doesn't open contacts app

Comment: I've updated my answer @user123 and now it includes the solution to your problem

Comment: thanks. it works fine. I want to select a contact and also get the information of that contact in my app. is it possible?

Comment: @Saeedeh Hey! Did you get any solution?

Comment: @shadow no, and I started to use java !

Comment: @user3764429 on deny my app getting crash, how can I solve this issue

Comment: @user3764429 thanks for your well explained solution, 

For my case the second scenario is working, but I want to know if there is any solution to access directly to specific contact page details using Linking ?